# encode with UTF-8 without BOM on salesforce

Tags: curl, utf-8, salesforce

I'm exporting some lists from salesforce with using cURL, 
but its exporting with UTF, but i need UTF with BOM,

any ways to export with BOM ?

Comment: What type of file? How are you currently using curl? You could just prepend the BOM to the result.

Comment: @Esailija how to prepend BOM to the result? BOM seems special set of characters not able to prepend them via Apex.